# Toο much work to cut the rest of that axle in half in Terminator 2?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

[image: The Terminator kneels naked in a partially destroyed room, a glowing metal object is circled]

What's with that thing in the middle of the tire? At a better resolution, you can see gears on the end of it. Shouldn't it be a conical shaped piece of glowing metal?

I don't know what that part's called but if its case is melted above and below it (and behind/to the right?) then the rest of it should be too.

It looks like a solid steel part that would be pretty hard to cut as needed. Did the Prop Master just forget to cut it or is there an **in-universe** mechanical reason why it appears intact?

Comment: Can you add an MS Paint-style arrow pointing at what you're asking about?

Comment: @Keen - Your wish is my command...

Comment: What extra attention are you expecting this question to receive that you haven't already had. It's clearly a production error and that's the answer.

Comment: In-universe lead me to think you weren't seeing what I was seeing and if you were, it was the result of sagging. New edit of Out-of Universe (added upon bounty) says, yes obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In-Universe:

The part you're referring to appears to have been housed inside the structure of the wheel, presumably part of the [hub face](https://www.venturestruckparts.com/images/help/Axle_Measurement_Diagram.jpg) or something within the axle itself.

Since a large chunk of the tyre has been removed by the [Time Displacement Sphere](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Time_Displacement_Equipment), it seems likely that the truck would settle and that various pieces could then extrude into the cavity left by the (now non-existent) bubble.

As you can see from your own photo, the wheel arch itself is also no longer completely flush to where the Displacement Bubble used to be...

### Out of Universe:

This is clearly a (very minor) production error. They do occasionally creep into even highly-funded films like this. If you get hung up on every [magically repairing window or visible boom mike](https://www.moviemistakes.com/film1268/page8), you'll go crackers.

I find that the best thing to do is to focus on "[Bellisario's Maxim](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim)"; That the story is being told by a small production team that (due to the limitations of the medium) has to work quickly, with limited budget and tight deadlines all while trying to turn out the best product it can.